# what are the main differences between ADODB and SqlClient in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

HI my task is to convert and old program that was using ADOOB connection to use SqlClient connection . What are the difference?

Comment: The main difference is with ADODB you use RecordSets. SqlClient runs via ADO.Net and doesn't have RecordSets, it has newer methods such as DataReaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADODB uses the older ADO library. This code exists mainly for compatibility with old code and to make it easier to port old code forward. It's also at a different level of abstraction. ADODB defines a set of criteria that objects for connecting to any database type can implement. SqlClient is specific to Sql Server. However, SqlClient implements the newer ADO.Net provider contract. Whenever possible, even when porting old code, prefer SqlClient or other ADO.Net provider.

Answer (score 5):

OleDb is more generic. If you ever move to a different database type in the future there's a good chance it'll have an Ole driver and you won't have to change as much code.

On the other hand, the Sql Server native driver is supposed to be faster as you said and it has nicer parameter support (parameters can use names and don't have to be in order).

There were some limitations in ado library some of the following were known limitations

1. Hierarchical recordsets aren’t supported.
2. Server-side cursors (other than FO-RO cursors) are supported only for Microsoft SQL Server databases.
3. Multiple, semicolon-delimited SQL statements are supported in Recordset.Open methods, but not in the Execute method of the Connection and Command objects.
4. Parameterized stored procedures are not supported with Oracle databases
5. Asynchronous execution is allowed for the Open method of Connection and Recordset objects, but not for the Execute method of the Connection and Command objects.
6. The UpdateBatch method of the Recorset object requires that the SQL source statement includes the key fields of all involved tables and doesn’t work with old-syntax JOIN statements, with nested SELECT statements, and with derivate tables.
7. The SELECT statement used to open server-side keyset and dynamic cursors must include at least one non-nullable key column.
8. The Move method doesn’t work and raises an exception with serverside dynamic cursors.
9. The Index, Seek, MarshalOption, StayInSync members of the Recordset class aren’t implemented and are marked as obsolete.
10. The PageSize, Clone, and Find members of the Recordset class aren’t implemented for keysets and other server-side cursors.
11. The CommandStream, Dialect, NamedParameters, and Prepared members of the Command class aren’t implemented and are marked as obsolete.
12. The ReadText, WriteText, and SkipLines methods of the Stream class aren’t implemented and are marked as obsolete.
13. A few dynamic properties of the Connection or Recordset objects aren’t supported.
14. The ADODB.Record class isn’t supported.

Some of the features are partially or not supported

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The [System.Data.SqlClient namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) is different from [Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , but not so much that a look at the documentation shouldn't set you in the right path, so long as both use SQL server for their back-end.

Both use connections and allow for either "command" or "record-set" interfaces, but the former is, for obvious reasons, more tightly integrated into .Net.  You'll probably find a lot of instances where VB.Net code in your application can be removed, as you'll have that functionality built right into the newer interface.